# How to get client IP address in Microsoft Edge browser using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows, webrtc, microsoft-edge

I have tried using webRTC to find client IP address using Javascript by following the below link and I am successful in Chrome and Firefox but it didn't work in Microsoft Edge.

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/257/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-with-javascript-only

How to get Client IP address in Microsoft Edge browser using Javascript?

Do we have any other alternate for WebRTC to get IP address in Edge browser?

Comment: Make sure it is compatible WebRTC in Edge, https://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection.

Comment: webRTC didn't work. Is there any other alternate?

Comment: One of the options listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35123097/11496299) should work.

Comment: @BenMelville I need to get the private client IP. All the solutions gives my public IP. I will edit my question.

Comment: AS this is marked duplicate by Brad, modified my question to for private IP as part of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59244292/how-to-get-private-client-ip-address-in-microsoft-edge-browser-using-javascript